# Is it possible to change dependencies in a maven plugin programmatically?

Tags: maven, plugins, artifact

I am building a maven plugin which I would like to attach to a project which uses the artifact of another project which I'm building. 
For instance:
Project A --> Project B
I could run Project A with two different branches of Project B so I would like to checkout and generate the artifact on demand.
Is it possible to access the maven dependencies of the project and remove or add one or trigger another project build?

Comment: You can read the dependencies of a project but you can not change the dependencies of a project via a plugin furthermore I strongly discourage this. And what kind of artifact would you like to generate? Why not simply putting the information in your pom file?

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering... Let me explain better... I have a project A that relay on the JAR file of project B... What's the issue here?... In Project B, I am doing certain changes that wont work with the common Project A...So, we would have two version of Project B (the one that relates to a branch that works with master of Project A and another one that works with another version of Project A -because it has some more apis-).
So my idea would be to tell the plugin (which I have added to Project A) to work with "X" branch from Project B... Do you get the idea ?...

Comment: Is the jar in project A a separated module ? So you have a Project B which has a dependency to Project A (or maybe a child of Project A) ? If it's a separate module extract that as a separate project and use correct versioning (may be SNAPSHOT's to support development easier) or think of extracting the module into complete separate project which has a separate release cycle..